# RegDBKeyExist not working

Tags: installshield

**I have a registry entry as below:**

```
 RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
 szKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Installer\\UserData\\S-1-5-18\\Products\\00004109610090400000000000F01FEC";
 nResult = RegDBKeyExist(szKey);
```

In my registry, the above key exists. But the value returned is -1. If I search for key exists till 'products', it returns 1 properly. The product key is spelled right, because I have copied from registry. What could be the problem?

Please leave your inputs

Comment: I found the problem.

Actually I was searching for a 64 bit key in 32 bit path. That's why the search results shows wrong result.

Comment: You shouldn't be searching the registry for Windows Installer artifacts anyway; use the relevant Msi* API.